# How can I check a click on a child component using jest, if the callback isn't passed as prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following component:

```
  <MaxFrContainer data-test="wellness-report-card">
      <PrimaryBlueButton
       onClick={() => {
        // open popup
        }}
       >
        generate
      </PrimaryBlueButton>
  </MaxFrContainer>
```

Jest complains that the `onClick` call isn't tested, but how do I test it? Whatever he callback would be, it is defined within the component and not passed down as a prop. Also, this similar thing repeats in my code. Sometimes it opens a popup, sometimes it makes an API call.

How do I get these tested

Comment: If you were using a more natural testing paradigm you could easily use React-Testing-Library and target the button text and simulate a click. Have you unit tested `PrimaryBlueButton` to know it correctly invokes its `onClick` callback?

Comment: @DrewReese yes the button definitely works and have been thoroughly tested. I've never heard of react-testing-library, just been using jest/enzyme, I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specified what do you do in `//open popup`?

If I would create such component there are should be separate module with business logic, and in onClick handler I should just call some method from this module.

```
<MaxFrContainer data-test="wellness-report-card">
      <PrimaryBlueButton
       onClick={() => MaxFrContainerController.clickHandler()}
       >
        generate
      </PrimaryBlueButton>
  </MaxFrContainer>
```

And to test onClick you should only check that `clickHandler` of mock `MaxFrContainerController` was called.

Comment: Well open popup might just be changing a state inside this component which will render the popup. I guess in that case I would check if that state has changed. Perhaps my issue is by trying to assume all of these should be tested similarly, where the test should actually be different per each case based on what the click would actually do.

Comment: So in this case I should know what kind of components do you use. If it's class components perhaps you can mock _setState_ method. For function component it's better to find some package to help you.